# Ubuntu 14.04 will not install!

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. A clean install with a blank hard disc. The install always stops partway through with the screen saying "Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source". I have tried both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions, both via DVD and USB stick with the same result. The laptop does not hang, the cursor moves and I can scroll back and forth through the welcome screens, but there is no hard disc or DVD activity, even after several hours.

The laptop has an AMD Turion64 processor and 2GB of memory.

Does anybody have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

Moved from comments:

`bcmwl-kernel-source` is a package containing a source files for your wireless interface card driver. The system uses these to configure/build the kernel module for the driver. This is a driver for legacy cards and have some known bugs (no support from upstream and relatively rarely used). It is hanging on the package install step, which is probably also the step that loads the kernel module (driver).

The easiest way to get around this is to disable "install updates and extra drivers" during your installation, and then deal with configuring the wireless card after you get your system running

[Source + More information](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211923&page=4)